# Use ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) but insert all data into a database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

I just read some questions like my and I searched for a few days but nothing.

I'm new on php so I can create only simply codes.

I worked every time with html forms, and I used:

```
<form method = "post" action = "examplepage.php">
```

Some days ago I discover:

```
<form method = "post" action = "<? php echo htmlspecialchars ($ _ SERVER [" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
```

I have read I can use it doing everything on the first page (errors ...) without create a new page.

**My question is:**
If before I had a `example.php` page with my database sensitive data and connection info, now after I write all (form code + all the controls on the datas) how can I create the connection with the database and insert datas in it without write database datas on the first page (everyone can read it)?

Comment: You need to format your code - add a blank line above and below in it and start the code with 4 spaces

Comment: `<? php echo htmlspecialchars ($ _ SERVER [" PHP_SELF "]);?>` means that the page will submit on the same page as the form action = example means that the page when the form is submitted it will redirect to example.php with the form data

Comment: Clients do not see your PHP pages, they see the result of running the PHP page.  So database info is not viewable by them.  But you could (and should) put that information in a separate file and use `require_once()` to import it in your running pages.  This way you only type it once, and have only 1 place to change it (if required later).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Ok. But if on action I write `<? php echo htmlspecialchars ($ _ SERVER [" PHP_SELF "])` where do I can declarate the name of the second php page (example.php)?

Comment: The only thing that matters is HTTP requests. You send an HTTP request to a URL, the server does something and returns a response. What matters is what happens when you send an HTTP GET request to your server, and what happens when you send an HTTP POST request to your server. File names do not matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate file for database connection and simply include that connection file on other pages where you want to perform database queries.

```
<?php
 include('database.php');
?>
```

Comment: suppose you have created the database file as dataabse.php and include that file as  include('database.php');

Comment: I have edited the main answer for showing how to include the file

Comment: ok i used include with my php file (wich contains instructions for writing datas on database). When I try to open the page on chrome (page I uploaded on my site) it says error http 500 and cant open it. I included the php file at the end of the first page before `</body` using `<?php
 include('insert.php');
?>`

Comment: stackoverflow editor says "too long by 141 characters"

Comment: can you include your insert.php (which contains database connection) at the top of the page before your html code starts

Comment: I can try, but I think the problem it's not of my insert.php file, because when on action i use insert.php the page runs good and on the database i can see my datas, i want to use `php self` for doing more controls on the inputs and preventing malicious javascript/html code attacks